# Merge sort C# time and space efficiency

Tags: c#, sorting, complexity, mergesort

Please comment on time and space efficiency.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace JobInterviewTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class MergeSortUnitTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void MergeTest()
        {
            int[] array = new int[] { 5, 10, 1, 4, 2, 3, 7 };
            SortHalf(array, 0, array.Length-1); 

            int[] expectedOutput = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10 };
            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedOutput, array);
        }
        private void SortHalf(int[] array, int startIndex, int endIndex)
        {
            int mid;
            if (endIndex > startIndex)
            {
                mid = (endIndex + startIndex) / 2;
                SortHalf(array, startIndex, mid);
                SortHalf(array, mid + 1, endIndex);
                DoMerge(array, startIndex,mid+1, endIndex);
            }
        }

        private void DoMerge(int[] array, int startIndex, int mid, int endIndex)
        {
            int[] temp = new int[array.Length];
            int i, start, numOfElements, position;
            start = mid - 1;
            position = startIndex;
            numOfElements = endIndex - startIndex + 1;
            while((startIndex <= start)&& (mid <= endIndex))
            {
                if(array[startIndex] <= array[mid])
                {
                    temp[position++] = array[startIndex++];
                }
                else
                {
                    temp[position++] = array[mid++];
                }
            }
            while(startIndex <= start)
            {
                temp[position++] = array[startIndex++];
            }

            while(mid <= endIndex)
            {
                temp[position++] = array[mid++];
            }

            for (i = 0; i < numOfElements; i++)
            {
                array[endIndex] = temp[endIndex];
                endIndex--;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If anybody's wondering where to get the dll containing  `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` you can get it [through NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `mid = (endIndex + startIndex) / 2;` may overflow. A canonical idiom is

  ```
      mid = startIndex + (endIndex - startIndex)/2;
  ```
- Allocating (and deallocating) a new `temp` array in each invocation is a waste of time. Allocate the entire `temp` once, and pass it down, using same indices as for the actual array. Notice that it also allows to not copying data back from `temp` to `array`, which is another waste of time. Instead, ping-pong the arrays' roles.

  Of course, it doesn't affect the asymptotic, but should speed it up twofold.
- The algorithm looks much more natural with semi-open ranges (that is, `end` is one after the last element. This will avoid `+1` and `-1` index corrections, and use `<` instead of `<=` to compare indices.